# Array coordinates rotating

Tags: arrays, rotation

I was wondering, let's say I have an array of size `n x m`. I would like to implement a function which writes back the coordinates of an element rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise. Example is shown on the picture. Is there any clever way of doing that?

Example would be the coordinates `(0,0) -> (0,m)`

[image: Image]![1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question, the coordinate transformation you are looking for is:

```
rotate(<i,j>)=<j,m-i-1>
```

i.e. column j becomes row j, and row i becomes column m-i-1.

(Note: Assuming the initial matrix is of size mxn, your example is incorrect. <0,0> should be mapped to <0,m-1>)